# Ionic Email Composer Plugin Not Working for iOS 13+, Possible Workaround?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ios13, ionic-native

I am using Ionic's Email Composer Plugin for Cordova. Can be found here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/email-composer

The thing is I got it working completely fine on Android. You can open emails and send and all that perfectly. When it comes to iOS however the same method does not work. Below is the code I used the first attempt at this:

```js
this.emailComposer.isAvailable().then(available => {
                if (available) {
                    //Now we know we can send
                    this.emailComposer.open({
                        to: 'email@gmail.com',
                        subject: 'Reporting User ' + uid,
                        body: 'Message: ' + message + '/n/r' + 'Reason For Reporting: '
                    });
                }
            });
```

As stated before, this works completely fine on Android. With iOS however this did not work. So I tried another method with requesting permission from the user on iOS and then opening the email that way:

```js
if (this.platform.is('android')) {
            this.emailComposer.isAvailable().then(available => {
                if (available) {
                    //Now we know we can send
                    this.emailComposer.open({
                        to: 'email@gmail.com',
                        subject: 'Reporting User ' + uid,
                        body: 'Message: ' + message + '/n/r' + 'Reason For Reporting: '
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            this.emailComposer.requestPermission().then(perm => {
                if (perm) {
                    this.emailComposer.open({
                        to: 'email@gmail.com',
                        subject: 'Reporting User ' + uid,
                        body: 'Message: ' + message + '/n/r' + 'Reason For Reporting: '
                    });
                }
            });            
        }
```

Again, Android has no problems opening emails. But with iOS, it does not even ask the user for permission. Is there a simple way I can get this to work on iOS? The specifications:

```js
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 1.2.1
   @capacitor/core : 1.2.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.9.0
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : macOS Catalina
   Xcode             : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: So I heard online that the Ionic team is not really updating this plugin to try and get people to buy an Enterprise license from them. How accurate do you think this information is and if so, do you know anyone familiar enough with this plugin that may know how to update it?

Comment: Hi NotChad did you find any alternate solution for this?

Comment: ionic plugins are horrible now

Comment: also still looking for a solution ;-(